# How to compose "Maybe" lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

If I have lenses for a nested record, where each lens returns a `Maybe`, how can I get them to compose, so that if anything in the "traversal" returns a `Nothing` the final result is a `Nothing`?

```
data Client = Client
  {
    clientProperties :: Maybe Properties
  , ...
  }

data Properties = Properties
  {
    propSmtpConfig :: Maybe SmtpConfig
  , ...
  }

c :: Client 
c = undefined

smtp = c ^. (properties . smtpConfig) -- How to make these lenses compose?
```

**Edit** I tried a lot of options, but this is the best I could come up with. Looking for something cleaner:

```
(client ^. properties) >>= (view smtpConfig)
```

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for [the `_Just` prism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:_Just).

Comment: Thanks @Gurkenglas. Please submit this as an answer. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
client ^? properties . _Just . smtpConfig . _Just
```

Edit: Optics like lenses turn a small action into a big action. Optic composition is function composition. `_Just` turns an action on `a` into an action on `Maybe a`. Lenses can turn small reading actions into large reading actions and small writing actions into large writing actions, but `_Just` can't process reading actions because in a `Nothing` there is no `a`. Therefore `_Just` is a weaker optic than a lens, a traversal. A composed optic can always work with exactly those actions which all parts can work with. Therefore `properties . _Just . smtpConfig . _Just` is a traversal. `(^?)` uses a variation on reading actions which a traversal can work with: "Maybe read a value". Therefore the above line turns the trivially successful reading action `Just :: SmtpConfig -> Maybe SmtpConfig` into a large reading action `Client -> Maybe SmtpConfig`.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat there you go.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`_Just` prism](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.19/lens-4.15.1/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:_Just). Here's a contrived example:

```
> (Just (Just 1, ()), ()) & _1 . _Just . _1 . _Just +~ 1
(Just (Just 2,()),())
```

In your case, I think you want

```
properties . _Just . smtpConfig . _Just
```

Comment: does the `_Just` lens behave like a `fromJust`, i.e. will it throw an error if the value is a `Nothing`?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I hope there are no exceptions. It just doesn't set the value.

Comment: I do not need to **set** anything. I need to **get** only.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda, remember that getting in `lens` is done by modifying in a `Const` context. So from `Nothing` you get nothing.

Comment: In my case this fails with ` No instance for (Applicative  (Control.Lens.Internal.Context.Pretext (->) Text Text)) arising from a use of ‘_Just’`

Answer (score 4):

`traverse` is a valid [`Traversal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html), remember.

```
getSmtpConfig :: Traversal' Client SmtpConfig
getSmtpConfig = properties . traverse . smtpConfig . traverse
```

A `Traversal` is the best you can do here - you can't get a `Lens` - because there may not be an `SmtpConfig`. (A [`Lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:Lens) says "there's always exactly one of these things", whereas a `Traversal` says "there may be zero or many".)

This code actually produces the same `Traversal` as if you'd used [the `_Just` prism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44624359/7951906), but it's perhaps a little easier to understand if you haven't grokked prisms yet.

Note that since a `Traversal` might not find any results, you can't use [`^.`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:-94-.) to access a single result as you did in your question. You need to use the "safe head" operator [`^?`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-) (aka [`flip preview`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:preview)).

```
smtp :: Maybe SmtpConfig
smtp = c^?properties.traverse.smtpConfig.traverse
```